# How is this ArrayList add method working here?

Tags: java

I have made an ArrayList SYMTAB and i wanted to add element in it. But I am not able to understand this `TableRow` working inside the add. I am not able to get the idea of how it is working or what it is returning.

Another class is created named TableRow and there i have defined the constructors.

What is this code `new TableRow(parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[0])` returning or doing ?

```
ArrayList<TableRow> SYMTAB = new ArrayList<>();
SYMTAB.add(new TableRow(parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[0]));
```

**TableRow.java**

```
public class TableRow{
    public TableRow(String symbol, int address,int index) {
        super();
        this.symbol = symbol;
        this.address = address;
        this.index=index;

    }
}
```

Comment: It is the same thing as `TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);  SYMTAB.add(tableRow);` , you are allowed to call methods and constructors inside the parameters part of a method call .

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: are you inside AsyncTask ?

Comment: I am not able to understand what is being returned by this code "new TableRow(parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2], Integer.parseInt(parts[0])" and what is being added in the arraylist.

Comment: you are calling add() and provide a new Object. It is like creating a variable with new() and then adding this variable. Your constructor returns the created object, thats what the new() inside the add() method does

Comment: @ItFreak but the TableRow is not returning anything ?

Comment: The constructor creates and returns an *instance* of `TableRow`, which is then added to your list.  Or more accurately it returns a reference to a new object which is added to the list.

Comment: Now I got it what is going on, thanks everyone.

Comment: @glitterfart1337 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok probably I will get some minuses here but the importance is to understand :

Here : Your array list **has a** type `TableRow` which means you can add only that kind of object there . How do you initialize an object ? `new TableRow()` , but your constructor has some parameters also which means : it needs a `String` , an `int` and another `int` . Now if you lok carefully your `parts` is mostly a `String[]` type . Every index of it brings a single string according to the length of your array of `String[]` . Since your constructor needs a string and 2 integers , the `Integer.parseInt(parts[2])` is just converting those strings into ints ? Does this help you ?

Comment: Does the constructor is returning an object to add in the SYMTAB arraylist ?

Comment: The constructor is the object my friend . yes

Comment: Refer this link for deeper understanding of constructors 

https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-a-constructor-in-java/

Comment: You are welcome. But I would strongly suggest you to read something about constructors and then work

Answer (score 0):

assuming parts is your arguments, this line is creating a new object type TableRow. and adding that object in ArrayList which is type of TableRow. ArrayList is a collection of TableRow objects.

```
ArrayList<TableRow> SYMTAB = new ArrayList<>(); // initializing Arraylist type TableRow
SYMTAB.add(new TableRow(parts[1], Integer.parseInt(parts[2]), Integer.parseInt(parts[0])); //creating new object of tableRow and adding it to Arraylist.
```